# Is it possible to put the text below the image in the header or footer in phpExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

Based on [phpexcel_library/1.7.4/manual.html](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/phpexcel_library/1.7.4/manual.html#_Toc237519914) I can insert the text below the image, but is there a way to put text under the picture?

This is my code for the footer:

```
$workbook = new PHPExcel();

$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_HeaderFooterDrawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Footer Logo');
$objDrawing->setPath("footer_logo.png");
$objDrawing->setHeight(100);

$workbook->getActiveSheet()
    ->getHeaderFooter()
    ->addImage($objDrawing, PHPExcel_Worksheet_HeaderFooter::IMAGE_FOOTER_CENTER);
$workbook->getActiveSheet()
    ->getHeaderFooter()
    ->setOddFooter('&G&CVisible text behind the transparent image.');
$workbook->getActiveSheet()
    ->getHeaderFooter()
    ->setEvenFooter('&G&CVisible text behind the transparent image.');
```

Comment: Have you tried $workbook->getActiveSheet()
    ->getHeaderFooter()
    ->setOddFooter($objDrawing . '&G&CVisible text behind the transparent image.');

Comment: Is this possible by using MS excel? I couldn't find a way to change the header/footer image or text to overlap in front or behind the image.

Comment: @raphael75, it can not work, because the object $objDrawing is not convert onto the string. This is not correct.

Comment: Good question @ChristosLytras! I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this , I am sure it will give you an idea about what you can do .

http://doclecture.net/1-57789.html

using setOddFooter($objDrawing .....   will give you the access to it.

Comment: I looked at this website before I asked the question. I have not found on this web site solution to my problem...